# I don't understand a little section of the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

I understand the theorem from a general point of view, but there's this little part, which I don't.

This is the theorem, as explained by Richard Courant and Herbert Robbins:

[image]

**What I don't understand:**

[image]

What I get is that if P1 and Q1 where equal, this would happen:

$$\frac{m}{p1} = \frac{p1*p2*...*pr}{p1} = \frac{q1*q2*...*qs}{p1} | p1 = q1$$

$$\frac{m}{p1} = p2*...*pr = q2*...*qs $$

So, even though p1 and q1 dissapear, the number would still be the product of primes, and it would be smaller, since $\frac{m}{p1} < m$, so $m$ wouldn't be the smallest number product of primes. But, wouldn't this happen with just any $pr$ or $qs$ number?

$$\frac{m}{pr} = \frac{p1*p2*...*pr}{pr} = \frac{q1*q2*...*qs}{pr} | pr = qs$$

$$\frac{m}{pr} = p1*p2*... = q1*q2*... $$

So, I'm not getting quite the point. 
So, if anyone could explain this to me, it'd be really kind.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change the numbering and therefore assume that the first primes coincide. In other words, yes, the induction hypothesis can be applied as soon as we find some prime on both sides.

Comment: He's not saying it's unique to p_1 and q_1.  It is true for all p_i and q_k.   But choosing the smallest possible p and comparing it to the smallest possible q will become useful later.

Answer (score 1):

If $p_1=q_1$, then the factorizations must be different somewhere else; either in the number of factors (that is, $r\ne s$) or, if the number of factors is the same (that is, $r=s$), there must exist $i>1$ with $p_i\ne q_i$ (here the sorting $p_1\le p_2\le \dots\le p_r$ and $q_1\le q_2\le\dots q_s$ is used).

If we divide by $p_1=q_1$, we get, setting $m'=m/p_1$,
$$
m'=p_2p_3\dotsm p_r = q_2q_3\dotsm q_s
$$
and these are two different factorizations for $m'<m$. This is absurd.

The notation $p_2p_3\dotsm p_r$ might be confusing, but it helps in avoiding the need of dividing into special cases; it just means “the product of the remaining primes” and $1$ in case none remains.

Note that, for all we know, it could be $r=1$ or $s=1$ (in which case $m'=1$), so there's no point in using some index larger than $1$.

Even if we had excluded the case $r=1$ or $s=1$ (which would be easy), it wouldn't help taking a larger index for which $p_i=q_i$; the contradiction would be obtained in the same way, with slightly more complicated notation. Go for simplicity: if examining the first factor is sufficient, why bother with the others?

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is absolutely true - you could divide by ANY of the primes p and reduce to a smaller m.  The catch is that that doesn't help with this particular proof.  If you read further you will find the following sentence:

```
The latter is impossible, since all the q's are larger than p1.
```

This means that this proof depends on choosing to divide by the smallest p.  If a larger p is chosen, it is not clear how to infer that the impossible case is in fact impossible (if indeed it actually is impossible anymore).